# form checkbox animations are not working but form does work

Tags: reactjs, forms, ecmascript-6, formik

I'm having an odd issue with React and Formik(2.1).

I have a group of checkboxes on my page that the user can check on or off.

The behind-the-scenes part is working...the checkbox values that the user selects are being sent to the API backend and I see the selected values when I write them out to the browser console.

However, the actual checkbox that appears or disappeared inside the little checkbox square never shows.

I'm not sure why either. I tried updating to the latest version of Formik and React, but it doesn't change.

Since the actual values are still being passed, I can't figure out a way to debug it.

Here is the React component that generates the checkboxes:

```
const PlayerList = () => {

const [data, setData] = useState([]);

useEffect(() => {
    const fetchData = async () => {
        const result = await axios(
            'https://localhost:44376/api/players',
        );
        setData(result.data);
    };
    fetchData();
}, []);

return (
    <>
        {data.map((item, index) => (
            <label key={index}>
                <Field id={item.id} key={index} type="checkbox" name="gamePlayers" value={item.id} />
                {item.name}
            </label>
        ))}
    </>

);
}
export default PlayerList;
```

This component will generate form inputs that look like this:

```
<input name="gamePlayers" id="1" type="checkbox" value="1">
```

And here is the React component with the formik form:

```
<Formik
        initialValues={{
            gamePlayers: [],
            email: "",
            name: "",
            phone: ""
        }}
        onSubmit={async values => {
            await new Promise(resolve => setTimeout(resolve, 500));
            axios({
                method: "POST",
                url: "https://localhost:44376/api/gameentry",
                data: JSON.stringify(values)
            });
            console.log(JSON.stringify(values, null, 2));
        }}

    >
        {props => {
            const {
                values,
                touched,
                isSubmitting,
                handleSubmit,
                handleReset,
                setFieldValue
            } = props;
            return (
                <form onSubmit={handleSubmit}>

                    <div id="gameSection">Game Information</div>
                    <div id="players">
                        <label htmlFor="gamePlayers">
                            Game Player Type (check all that apply)
                        </label>
                        <PlayerList />
                    </div>
            );
        }}
    </Formik>
</div>
);
```

So everything looks ok, the form looks good.  It's just the checkbox animations are not working and I can't think of a way to debug because, technically, it's working.

Has anyone ever seen something like this?

Here is a link to a code sandbox. It's a bit different because I had to modify it to work within the sandbox enviroment.

https://codesandbox.io/s/inspiring-hodgkin-exufn

Thanks!

Comment: Can you share your code on sandbox, that should help me debug.. much better

Comment: @BarunPatro OK I made one.  It's a bit different than my real project because I had to modify it to work within the sandbox environment.  Thanks!

Comment: I have posted my answer.. let me know, if you need anything

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Implementing a checkbox in Formik can be tricky. you see you have to pass the JSX of input along with its label into the `component` prop.

Please find my work below.

https://codesandbox.io/s/lingering-https-yw0jl